# How to get stream/list of commit sha's from Bitbucket repo

Tags: curl, get, bitbucket-api

If I put this url in the browser search bar I get JSON back:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/interos/{b89131e7-a658-4bef-93b3-e4c90a13b0cf}/commits/
```

but if I use cURL like so:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -u "${bitbucket_email}:${bitbucket_password}" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/interos/{b89131e7-a658-4bef-93b3-e4c90a13b0cf}/commits/
```

then I seem to get HTML back (with or without the Accept header)

*does anyone know why I am getting HTML instead of JSON?*

I am trying to follow the restful API docs here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commits

Comment: I also added `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` to the curl command to no avail! Still get html not json! :(

Comment: What is that html content showing?